# changing ownership on NFS shared ZFS storage - quota exceeded

Tags: nfs, zfs, chown, quota, nis

I have very bizarre problem. I have CentOS server 6.10 and ZFS storage.
Now storage is configured long time ago by someone, and I found out that for certain user there is a quota set.

when I check on the filesystem I get output this

```
zfs# zfs get quota volume/local/default/users
NAME                         PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
volume/local/default/users  quota     none   default
```

so from this I can see that on parent folder there is no quota set, but when I check particular user by using this command:

```
 zfs# quota -v user
    Disk quotas for user (uid 1000):
    Filesystem     usage  quota  limit    timeleft  files  quota  limit    timeleft
    /export/mail  930552 10485760 10485760           -      -      -      -           -
    /export/users
             2147483646 31457280 31457280 NOT STARTED      -      -      -           -
```

so I can see that user

> user

has set quota.

Now, this ZFS has been mounted on CentOS 6.10 with this values in /etc/fstab:

```
zfs.mydomain.com:/export/users  /users   nfs  defaults,_netdev    0 0
```

and I can access /users folder.
The problem starts when I want to use chown command:

```
chown -R test:grp /home/user/mnt/child_fldr
```

Please note that the "test" user is NIS user which I also tested with ypcat passwd, if I can get list of all users from NIS. (and I do), so this is not a problem.
The output of the error is:

> chown: changing ownership of `/home/user/mnt/child_fldr/temp': Disk quota exceeded

Now to be even more confused, when I try to change an ownership by using local user account, I have no problem of changing it, but using NIS user, I get some dumb Disk quota exceeded message.

For the test, I have tried to remove "quotas" file in the parent directory of child_fldr, and remount drive, with no success.
Also on ZSF I tried to completely remove quota for testing by using quotaoff -a command, again still no progress.

How can I solve my problem to be able again to change ownership of the directory?

Answer (score 0):

failed to realize a fairly simple thing, even though I run through Oracle manual:

Its a user quota not filesystem... :-)

[Oracle Solaris ZFS Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/gazvb.html#gazud)

So command which I needed was this:

```
zfs set userquota@1000=none volume/local/default/users
```